# rabbitmq messages not consumed - tcp closure

Tags: rabbitmq, consumer

UPDATE - apparently a tcp closure
I see on rabbit server:

=ERROR REPORT==== 24-Jan-2015::03:22:00 ===
closing AMQP connection <0.1070.22> (209.151.226.37:38040 -> 192.168.80.81:5672):
{inet_error,etimedout}

This conections appears alive on my app's side. How to prevent this? tcp keepalive parms look OK.

I have two apps. 
One, "processor", consumes jobs from a queue and sends replies to a response queue. 
The other, "responder" consumes from this response queue and talks to a database.

I had some replies which apparently made it into the response queue because upon restart of the responder they were handled and database updated appropriately. But before that restart where were they?

How can I pinpoint why they weren't PREVIOUSLY handled? That responder seems to have been running fine.

In the responder I do 
res = amqp_consume_message(Cx->conn, genvelope, &tqb, 0);
I ack ( not multiple ) after replying to the database. 
I have prefetch at 11.

The processor was closed and restarted a few times during this FWIW. Also the processor is the one that establishes the exchange used for the replies; the responder connects to it.

I have the management url up. 
I saw no indication that the replies were available from the consume(), which makes sense since the database wasn't updated. The processor did do its processing and put a reply in the response queue according to logs.

In separate testing I saw that messages in the reply aren't destroyed by restarting the processor - reply exchange is durable.

The apps generally work. 
Any debugging suggestions or conceptual info that might be relevant would be appreciated.